# Is there a way to use the WPDB class into a non-wordpress project?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Because the WordPress wpdb class is so easy to use, I want to try using it into a **non-wordpress** project.
I tried to copy `wp-db.php` into my working directory and tried the following script on a separate file

```
<?php

require_once("wp-db.php");

$mydb = new wpdb('myuser','mypassword','mydatabase','myhost');

$rows = $mydb->get_results("SELECT column1 FROM table1");

foreach ($rows as $obj)
   echo $obj->column1."<br/>";
endforeach;

?>
```

but then I couldn't make it to display the data.

Is there a way to use the wpdb class on a non-wordpress project?

Comment: Of course yes. You just need to require the `wp-load.php` file it will load the most of the Wordpress enviroment to your custom project.

Comment: Yes you can....btw, when you do a var_dump($rows), which output do you get??

Comment: @RobertRozas $rows is empty

Comment: @AbelMelquiadesCallejo did you check the function _construct of the wabd class...pls post is the output of var_dump($mybd); ?

Comment: the following script gives an error
`<?php
require_once("wp-db.php");
$mydb = new wpdb('myuser','mypassword','mydatabase','myhost');
var_dump($mydb);
?>`
but displays a non-null value of `$mydb`

Comment: @RobertRozas, what do you mean by __check the function _construct__ ?

Comment: @RahilWazir, the project is using a non-wordpress database. is `wp-load.php` still needed for that?

Comment: Is the wp-db.php script in the same directory?

Comment: Just wait a little bit more...i'm refactoring the wp-db class right now..

Answer (score 0):

### Test code(test.php):

```
<?php

require_once("wp-db.php");

$mydb = new wpdb('root','','mysql','localhost');

$row = $mydb->get_results("select * from user limit 1");

var_dump($row);


?>
```

### Modified wp-db class(wp-db.php): http://codepad.viper-7.com/cooNyJ